# Subir fichero *.xls genera nulo, en cambio *.xlsx funciona correctamente

Tags: php, html

Un formulario sencillo para seleccionar un fichero.

```
<form role="form"  method="POST" action="procesaExcel.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

         <input type="file" id="inputXML" name="inputExcel" >
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Subir</button>

</form>
```

Ahora el fichero php que procesa el formulario.

```
<?php
      var_dump($_FILES["inputExcel"]["tmp_name"]);
?>
```

El problema viene que cuando subo un fichero con la extensión *.xlsx el fichero php lee el contenido, pero si la extensión es *.xls lo que recibo es null.

He mirado un poco los tipos de codificados para los formularios:

```
.xls  - application/vnd.ms-excel
.xlsx - application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
```

Y no funciona con ninguno de los dos.

¿alguien ha tenido un problema similar?

Answer (score 0):

Pues el error era por el tamaño que permitía en el fichero `php.ini` exactamente la linea encargada es: `upload_max_filesize = 1024M`.